# useState not setting initial state?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a `SettingsDialog` component that has the initial settings passed in as props. I'm then using `useState` to set the current form values initially to the passed in settings:

```
export default function SettingsDialog({ settings }) {
  const [values, setValues] = useState(settings);
}
```

However, this doesn't seem to be working. The `values` state object is always an empty object. If I add two `console.log` statements:

```
export default function SettingsDialog({ settings }) {
  const [values, setValues] = useState(settings);

  console.log('settings:', settings);
  console.log('values:', values);
}
```

the first logs out the settings object being passed in, but the second logs out an empty object.

Am I not understanding how the `useState` hook is supposed to work, or am I just doing something wrong?

Comment: can you post an example where its not working? [I can't replicate it.](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-icgkq)

Comment: I've had this issue in enzyme, any idea what was causing it?

Answer (score 9):

The reason why you get the empty values (but the settings has value) is because, when you render the page the Dialog got initialized, but at this time, the value of both settings and values are null; then when you open the Dialog, the settings value has been initialized. But the values hasn't get updated;

if you wanna the values keep updating with settings, add:

```
useEffect(() => {
    setValues(settings);
}, [settings]);
```

Comment: This solved it for me as well, but I'm not sure how you figured `the value of both settings and values are null`. The console.log for `settings` logs something, so how can `settings` be null?

Comment: Usually chrome browser inspect print out value after the whole pages get rendered. If you wanna see the property values during rendering, add some break point, then check the value.

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted is working as expected:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

function SettingsDialog({ settings }) {
  const [values, setValues] = React.useState(settings);

  console.log("settings:", settings); // {default: "value"}
  console.log("values:", values); // {default: "value"}

  return null;
}

function App() {
  return <SettingsDialog settings={{ default: "value" }} />;
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

There are two possible issues I could think of:

1. `settings={{ default: "value" }}` isn't being passed when using `SettingsDialog`
2. `SettingsDialog` is being re-used between renders and it's not reinitializing. If this is your problem, make sure to have the `key` attribute set. Here is an example of what it could look like if trying to switch between different `SettingsDialog` with and without a key: https://codesandbox.io/s/with-and-without-keys-9o793

Answer (score 0):

I seem to be having the same issue. Below is the relevant code to the issue I'm having. When i pass uid as props and try to initialise state of Uid here, i get an error message saying useState cannot be undefined :/

```
export default function Home(props) {

    const [ Uid, setUid ] = useState(props.uid);
}
```